# Sequence of robot's move using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code and I want to ensure the order in which the robot's legs move using wait() and notify(). Here is the code:

```
public class Leg implements Runnable {

    private final Object monitor = new Object();
    private final String name;

    public Leg(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                move();
                monitor.notify();
                try {
                    monitor.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
    private void move() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Leg("left")),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Leg("right"))
        ).join();
    }
}
```

Right now the output is the below:

```
left 
right
// and then it stops moving.
```

I want the code continue moving (not only once). That's why it's interesting for me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that each your runnable (Leg) does both notify() and wait() on its own monitor. There is no communication between them. Create one single instance of monitor in the main method and pass this object to both Legs' constructor and do all synchronized/wait/notify on this one single instance.

Comment: @AnatolyG But it is already one instance in a class, isn't it? Could you show me in the code?

Comment: not sure I understand what does "one instance in a class" mean) You create 2 instances of Leg. For each instance its own private final Object monitor = new Object(); created in the constructor. But you have to share one single instance of the monitor: public class Leg implements Runnable {
    private final Object monitor; ... public Leg(String name, Object monitor) {...}} and do in the main: final Object monitor = new Object();
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Leg("left", monitor))...

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `Leg` object with 2 threads to process, for each thread you have a `monitor` object, so when you use `notify` and `wait`, it just effects to one thread (which thread is running currently):

```java
synchronized (monitor) {
    move();
    monitor.notify(); // notify current thread, it's no meaning
    try {
        monitor.wait(); // current thread will block here and there is no thread wake up it
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe it's what you need:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Leg implements Runnable {

    private final String name;
    private Leg nextLeg;
    private volatile boolean active;

    public Leg(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNextLeg(Leg nextLeg) {
        this.nextLeg = nextLeg;
    }

    public void active() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.active = true;
            notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (!active) {
                        wait();
                    }
                    move();
                    active = false;
                    nextLeg.active();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    private void move() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Leg left = new Leg("left");
        Leg right = new Leg("right");
        left.setNextLeg(right);
        right.setNextLeg(left);
        left.active();
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(left),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(right)
        ).join();
    }
}
```